# vagrant on windows need a second vagrant up

Tags: windows, vagrant

I do have an annoying bug using Vagrant on Windows.

Whenever I do start a new VM (after init or destroy) it will not recognize the Linux VM startup. I need to cancle the command using ctrl-c and kill the Machine in vIrtualBox. The second start or any start after this will work.

Any Idea how to find the root cause for this, or which command is executed during

"[default] Waiting for VM to boot. This can take a few minutes."

Stefan

Comment: This happens after it imports the box, right? Can you see the box booting in Virtualbox?

Answer (score 0):

This can be a few things... the easiest way to tell the exact problem is to see what the VM itself is stalling on by running it in [gui mode](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/virtualbox/configuration.html).

```
config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
  v.gui = true
end
```

It could be stuck at the grub prompt or something... it could also just be a bad image... perhaps try a different [Vagrant base box](http://www.vagrantbox.es/).